# Why CSS is breaking design on some user screen and some see it fine?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, screen-resolution

I am testing a page which is giving some users a broken/overflown design while some are getting it right and I cannot figure out why, but I managed to get screen stats for users with broken design, following is screen stats for users who see CSS elements like flex overflown
[image: other users]

and following is screen stats for people who see it correctly
[image: my screen]

What I manage to see s Device Pixel Ratio is different but does it matter and few other things. How can I fix the issue so every user can experience same layout,

Googling for device pixel ratio, I have tried to convert px based to rem.

Comment: Device Pixel Ratio is the issue, best to use REM

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I googled and told DPR doesn't affect text ot flexbox. Is it true?

Comment: DPR affects anything using `px` measurement